# API BB implementação em sistema web

Tags: php, api

Estou desenvolvendo um Projeto Web e necessito que ele gere um boleto para pagamento através de uma conta do Banco do Brasil.

Porém nunca trabalhei com gerador de boleto;

Alguém sabe informar se o BB disponibiliza alguma Web API ou como funciona para eu inserir este tipo de sistema em meu Projeto Web?

Caso o BB não disponibilize nenhuma ferramenta, alguém recomenda alguma que já utilizou?

Comment: Se com um sistema de verdade (aplicativo, não web) a gente já sofre com o BB pra fazer uma simples remessa, imagino que com um "site" gerador de boletos vai sofrer mais ainda. Já adianto que uma coisa é gerar o boleto, e a outra é integrar com o sistema do banco (fazer a remessa). Sugiro baixar os manuais do site do banco para começar. Esses dias estou trabalhando de migrar um cliente do BB pra Caixa pq ao menos a Caixa tem contrato com algumas VANs que incluem acesso direto pelo cliente (mesmo assim, a integração ainda é desnecessariamente burocrática).

Comment: Se é boleto registrado vai ter problemas, se for sem registro pode usar phpboleto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recentemente o Banco do Brasil disponibilizou uma API para desenvolvedores.

Site oficial:
https://developers.bb.com.br

Documentação:
https://developers.bb.com.br/docs/

Mas o projeto ainda está em fase Beta.
Portanto é preciso fazer o cadastro e aguardar eles liberarem a ferramenta para testes e implementações.

Estou aguardando ansiosamente a minha liberação.

## Atualização

Caso tenha interesse em testar a API de Boletos, siga as instruções do @Pedro_Begotti em:

https://comunidade-beta.labbs.com.br/t/geracao-de-boleto-para-recebimento/251